# Basic text combat game javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, constructor, format

I'm pretty new to javascript so forgive me if I am a bit slow. I was looking to create a basic text combat game I can run through the console. The idea is to first ask the user for their character name. I was planning on using this:

```
console.log("Character name:");
var character_name = prompt("Character name:");
```

I'm using `repl.it` so `prompt` doesn't actually print out the string "Character name:", that is why I'm using `console.log` to see it in the console.

After they have given their character a name, I want them to be able to choose from three different classes: wizard, knight, archer. I'll do that in similar fashion:

```
console.log("Please choose your class: wizard, knight, rogue");
var character_class = prompt("Please choose your class: wizard, knight, archer");

if (character_class == "wizard"){
    var my_hero = wizard;
} else if (character_class == "knight"){
    var my_hero = knight;
} else (character_class == "archer");{
    var my_hero = archer;
} 

var wizard = new Character(character_name,"wizard",50,15,8,10);
var knight = new Character(character_name,"knight",100,5,3,20);
var archer = new Character(character_name,"archer",75,7,5,25);

function Character(name,characterClass,health,damage,heal,dodge){
    this.name = name,
    this.characterClass = characterClass,
    this.health = health,
    this.damage = damage,
    this.heal = heal,
    this.dodge = dodge;
}

console.log(my_hero)
```

So, what I'm trying to do is at the end of the 'character creation' stage, I want to be able to call `my_hero` and see his stats. However, when I do this, it shows the stats for the archer and not wizard/knight if chosen. Here is what I see in the console:

```
Character name:
 napp
Please choose your class: wizard, knight, archer
 wizard
{ name: 'napp', characterClass: 'archer', health: 75, damage: 7, heal: 5, dodge: 25 }
```

Keep in mind that I'm new and this post may change as more questions may come up. Thanks for your patience and all tips/advice is welcome. If there is a better way of doing this please dont hesitate in presenting that way.

Comment: hey, I just answered a question 'Reading a file into Ruby program' while you deleted it, not very nice

Answer (score 2):

I would choose the consctructor approach, but more like this

```
var Gandalf = new Character("Gandalf", "wizzard", 50, 15, 8);

function Character(name, characterClass, health, damage, heal){
    this.name = name,
    this.characterClass = characterClass,
    this.health = health,
    this.damage = damage,
    this.heal = heal,
    this.dodge = Math.random() * 100 + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [Commander](http://tj.github.io/commander.js/) library.

also see this post :

- [First Node.js Command-line Application](http://tutorialzine.com/2014/09/creating-your-first-node-js-command-line-application/)